# Combine 2 javascript functions into 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inherited some old code and i'm trying to clean it up, I am using jQuery on the site so it would be nice to keep things clean and simple by using that.

```
function address_finder_callback() {
    address_finder_setter('addressPostCode', 'addressLine1', 'addressLine2', 'addressLine3', 'addressLine4');
}

function address_finder_setter(obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4) {
    var formElement;
    var buttonClicked = document.getElementById('addressFinderPanelForm_buttonClicked').value;

    if (buttonClicked) {
        formElement = 'addressFinderPanelForm_postcode'
        var hiddenField = document.getElementById(formElement).value;
        document.getElementById(obj0).value = hiddenField;
        hiddenField = "";

        formElement = 'addressFinderPanelForm_line0';
        hiddenField = document.getElementById(formElement).value;
        document.getElementById(obj1).value = hiddenField;
        hiddenField = "";

        formElement = 'addressFinderPanelForm_line1';
        hiddenField = document.getElementById(formElement).value;
        document.getElementById(obj2).value = hiddenField;
        hiddenField = "";

        formElement = 'addressFinderPanelForm_line2';
        hiddenField = document.getElementById(formElement).value;
        document.getElementById(obj3).value = hiddenField;
        hiddenField = "";

        formElement = 'addressFinderPanelForm_line3';
        hiddenField = document.getElementById(formElement).value;
        document.getElementById(obj4).value = hiddenField;
        hiddenField = "";
    }
}
```

I figured it out and used jQuery to tidy it up -

### Answer

```
function address_finder_callback() {

    var postCode = $('#addressFinderPanelForm_postcode').val();
    var adressLine1 = $('#addressFinderPanelForm_line0').val();
    var addressLine2 = $('#addressFinderPanelForm_line1').val();
    var addressLine3 = $('#addressFinderPanelForm_line2').val();
    var addressLine4 = $('#addressFinderPanelForm_line3').val();

    $("#addressPostCode").val(postCode);
    $("#addressLine1").val(adressLine1);
    $("#addressLine2").val(addressLine2);
    $("#addressLine3").val(addressLine3);
    $("#addressLine4").val(addressLine4);

}
```

Comment: Where is the question?? ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be more suited (and less flamed) if posted here... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first function seems kind of pointless?

```
function address_finder_callback(obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4) {
    var formElement;
    var buttonClicked = document.getElementById('addressFinderPanelForm_buttonClicked').value;

    if (buttonClicked) {
        formElement = 'addressFinderPanelForm_postcode'
        var hiddenField = document.getElementById(formElement).value;
        document.getElementById(obj0).value = hiddenField;
        hiddenField = "";

        formElement = 'addressFinderPanelForm_line0';
        hiddenField = document.getElementById(formElement).value;
        document.getElementById(obj1).value = hiddenField;
        hiddenField = "";

        formElement = 'addressFinderPanelForm_line1';
        hiddenField = document.getElementById(formElement).value;
        document.getElementById(obj2).value = hiddenField;
        hiddenField = "";

        formElement = 'addressFinderPanelForm_line2';
        hiddenField = document.getElementById(formElement).value;
        document.getElementById(obj3).value = hiddenField;
        hiddenField = "";

        formElement = 'addressFinderPanelForm_line3';
        hiddenField = document.getElementById(formElement).value;
        document.getElementById(obj4).value = hiddenField;
        hiddenField = "";
    }
}
```

and call that directly

can be reduced to:

```
    function address_finder_callback(obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4) {
            var formElement;
            var buttonClicked = document.getElementById('addressFinderPanelForm_buttonClicked').value;

            if (buttonClicked) {
document.getElementById(obj0).value = document.getElementById(addressFinderPanelForm_postcode).value;
document.getElementById(obj1).value = document.getElementById(addressFinderPanelForm_line0).value; document.getElementById(obj2).value = document.getElementById(addressFinderPanelForm_line1).value;
document.getElementById(obj3).value = document.getElementById(addressFinderPanelForm_line2).value;
document.getElementById(obj4).value = document.getElementById(addressFinderPanelForm_line3).value;
            }
        }
```

and even more if you use jquery and loop it, but you get the drift

Comment: Sorry, but there's still about 75% of that code that could be removed.  This was a really half-hearted attempt.

Comment: he just asked to combine it :D but ok

Comment: Thanks @Fonzy but I figured it out! :)

Comment: np, happy to help the 25% :P